# Java application is not terminated even after successful execution

Tags: java, selenium-chromedriver, terminate

Screenshot that the terminate button is still in red:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpnWf.png]

```
package seleniumProjectTutorial;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class SeleniumWebDriver {
    WebDriver driver;   
    
    public void invokeBrowser() {
        try {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
                               "D:\\Selenium\\Drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.get("https://www.google.com");
            driver.close();
            driver.quit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SeleniumWebDriver myobject = new SeleniumWebDriver();
        myobject.invokeBrowser();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try run in debug mode or putting some SysOut statement to determine at which line your program is stuck, and post the result.

Answer (score 0):

I have used `System.exit(0);` as workaround.